# How to get the "Better Off Dead" achievement in Plants vs. Zombies

Tags: achievements, plants-vs-zombies

The "Better Off Dead" achievement can be completed if you get a streak of 10 in "I, Zombie Endless". I understand that much.

This mode is really hard and I cannot get my streak near 10 games in a row, although I cannot put my finger on my main mistakes. I am happy if I can win 7 in a row. Are there any common tactics I can apply to improve my game or are there any common mistakes I should avoid? For example I have no idea if it is always best to send single zombies, or if I should combine more than one zombie in some situations.

While searching the Internet for guides I found someone claiming that the use of the "Lead Dancer" Zombie is often key - a Zombie type I usually don't like to use. Under which circumstances is it good concerning cost and value?

Comment: I have found the I zombie levels easy...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really have to know the advantages of each zombie and how best to counter the plants. Generally what I did was,

- Aim for the flowers to generate more sun.
- Use as few zombies as possible
- Get the Magnetshroom out in the start to be able to use the metal wearing zombies
- Digger Zombie can take a whole row of plants out for just 175 sun, if there are no Spikeweed, Starfruit and Split Pea. 50 sun for the Imp when all else is dead.
- Imp dies from very little, just use him as a collector or as a sacrifice.
- Conehead Zombie is the standard sacrifice, as he can survive longer and possible eat plants as well
- Pole Vaulting Zombie can be used to save a little sun by jumping over a plant that might otherwise kill normal zombie. Note also that it can jump away from the first attack made by Chompers
- Buckethead Zombie can get very far, just be wary of instant killers and slowers combined with a lot of damage
- Football Zombie is the fast and heavy hitter. He is just expensive. He can however often be cheaper than buying 3 or 4 coneheads.
- Last we have Screen Door Zombie, Dancing Zombie, Ladder Zombie and Bungee Zombie which are only situational. I seldom use these and I found they require more planning than the other ones.

I hope this is helpful and good luck getting the achievement.

Comment: I found the key to getting the achievement was saving up sun for the latter levels by using well-placed Dancing Zombies.

Comment: Just don't use metallic zombies around magnet shrooms in a 5x5. Here are the metallic zombies: digger zombies(pickaxe) bucket head football zombies screen door zombies ladder zombies( ladder will still be sucked away if deployed ).